# Typesafe activator not starting

Tags: akka, typesafe

I installed typesafe activator(Windows) for using akka frame work. But when i am trying to start the activator it is not opening in the browser as mentioned on the Akka website. I tried opening it using command prompt but it is showing "jansi 1.11 could not be retrieved" error. How to reslove this?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you can't download the right version of the jansi.jar which unfortunately isn't included in the download.

If you are using a web proxy on Windows you have to follow the configuration steps described here http://typesafe.com/activator/docs in the section "Behind a proxy"

Answer (score 1):

try setting the *http_proxy* environment variable. It worked for me. See [this](http://kaamka.blogspot.de/2009/06/httpproxy-environment-variable.html)